# Does ImageResizer work on external url's?

Tags: imageresizer

I am new to Image Resizer, I did a simple test for a file in my project and it worked fine, I tried external image url's and it didn't seem to work, is that possible?

Thanks, it worked great though for my first test.

Comment: you might need to download the file to your server first.

Answer (score 0):

ImageResizer can process remote URLs, but you have to [Install RemoteReader and use a special syntax](https://imageresizing.net/plugins/remotereader). Keep in mind that latency will be higher and you're depending on someone else's server to respond.